# Masonry Grid Layout

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using masonry grid for a blog content. How I will change the height of the grid if the screen is change? Tbh. I don't even know the calculations. For example; assume that I choose the Nexus 4 on device toolbar the element of grid will be like this;

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 2304px;">
```

If I choose Nexus 5;

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 2160px;">
```

Current:

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 1011.75px;">
```

***Javascript***

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var gridheight = $('.grid').height() * 4;
   $(".grid").height(gridheight);
}).resize();
```

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation and applying some common sense regarding HTML and CSS.

Comment: it will generate auto-height depend content area and grid height/width

Comment: Better to show issue and what are expecting?

Comment: I forgot to call the isotope minified js file. It's okay now. Anyways, thanks guys.